# Is it possible to create an http/REST server on Tizen OS for TV

Tags: tizen, television, tizen-web-app

I would like to control my Tizen TV over another external device. 
From the device I want to do something like open Webbrowser with url=... 
I test to open the webbrowser application from my application within Tizen, but I found nothing (for Tizen TV) to make a server (create a socket) which accept control command from outside.
Is it possible to do something like this? Or is it perhaps possible instead by using the voice recognition from the TV?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to device console ? If yes, you could try to use Python for this purposes. For example module BaseHTTPServer https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html